# HTML5 Drag andDrop to ActionScript FileReference

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, html, apache-flex, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to let **HTML5 FileAPI Drag and Drop file into an ActionScript FileReference object?**

I think GMail does it: It allows Drag and Drop in Google Chrome. But then ActionScript object is responsible for uploading files to the server. ActionScript is responsible for the ProgressBar too.

Maybe I could find an answer if I can analyze GMail code. Does anyone know if it is possible? I tried it, but I get a bunch of JavaScript without spaces. It is not possible to read in such form.

Any advice will help. If I get some answers on my own, I will post them here, so they can serve others.

Comment: I am pretty sure that a browser based Flash app cannot access the file system unless an action is dictated by the user.  As such, I suspect the functionality you think that Gmail uses is probably different.  That says, gmail is a web app you should be able to get all the source w/ your browsers view source.  Dissecting it backwards will not be an easy feat, though.

Comment: I don't think the uploading in GMail is still Flash (they changed it at least a year ago). As per your question, I'm also pretty sure it's not possible.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com:  I opened GMail in IE9. I saw the standard progress bar, as we know if now from Chrome, IE, and another web browsers. I disabled Flash in IE9. The file attachment upload status bar disappeared, which persuaded me, that GMail still uses Flash to show attachment upload progress bar. The Progress Bar itself is not a Flash object, but there must be flash routine behind it, which calculates upload progress and updates appropriate CSS values.

Comment: @Cay, please see my message above. Dissabling Flash has effect on the progress bar itself in Google Mail.

Comment: Haven't looked into it, but that's probably only for IE, and if you right click the button that triggers the "choose file" dialog, you will probably see Flash's context menu. In Chrome and Firefox I'm pretty sure there is no Flash involved in the uploading process.

Comment: @Cay: Yes, in  IE, I've just right-clicked on **Attach a file** button and I got a flash context menu. This is a clear proof that at least in  IE, Flash technology is still used in some routines.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Gmail uses the HTML5 drag and drop events, not flash.

Look up html5 datatransfer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I am sure, that GMail uses Flash at least in those browsers that do not support HTML5 FileApi. I did tests in IE9, and when I turned off Flash, GMail switched to simple upload without progress bar. When Flash was ON, GMail used nice upload with progress bars.

Comment: Its 2 different features. Html5 allows the drag and drop. Flash or html5 allows progress bars.